# Calculating area within buffer using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, intersection

I'm trying to calculate how much area of urban green areas are within a buffer of 20 meters from apartments. For this I use the buffer tool first and then try to use Intersect, as you can see in the image. So I only get the portion of the urban green areas who are within the buffer. [image: Buffer and Intersect]
However, all my apartments are coded with a column that's named ID in the point dataset. How can I preserve the ID of the apartments when I use Intersect?

Since I want to import this information in an Excel sheet it's important that the information matches with the ID of the apartments.

Edit:

I tried using the Tabulate Intersection as suggested, with my buffer polygons and my urban green areas and I believe it worked quite all right. The only problem seems to be that the ID of apartments that aren't in the buffer are disregarded as you can see in the table it doesn't go in ID number order.

[image: Tabluate Intersection result]

Comment: If the Points have a named ID column and you don't dissolve it away when you are buffering the ID column will remain after intersect

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of your attribute table before and after you've processed it?

Comment: "The only problem seems to be that the ID of apartments that aren't in the buffer are disregarded " Then it isn't Intersect tool you want, its Union Tool. With Union all features will remain

Comment: Union with buffer and urban green area polygon datasets only give me an error message "999999 : Error executing function." so that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you may want to try is the [Tabulate Intersection Tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/tabulate-intersection.htm)

> *Computes the intersection between two feature classes and cross-tabulates the area, length, or count of the intersecting features.*

It does require an ArcGIS Advanced license (I couldn't find the desktop tutorial, so I apologize that the article references Pro, but it does exist in Desktop)

[image]

Comment: [ArcMap help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/tabulate-intersection.htm) -- appears the same as Pro.